# Load to specific slide from clicking on image?

Tags: jquery, load, nivo-slider

I'm loading the nivo slider on image click, but I really need it to load to the specific slide that the image is on rather than just loading the the first slide each time.

I'll post some code here, but have also uploaded a working example here: 
http://caseymmiller.com/tests/dayOfPeachtree/test.html

```
function parseRunners(xml) {

$(xml).find("person").each(function(e,gridId,name,from,yearsRun,age,tweet,slideID,imgSrc,lilImg,bigImg,firstPos,slideSpot){

    gridID = $(this).attr("id");
    name = $(this).find("name").text();
    from = $(this).find("from").text();
    yearsRun = $(this).find("yrsrun").text();
    age = $(this).find("age").text();
    tweet = $(this).find("tweet").text();
    slideID = gridID + "div";
            jumpID = gridID + "jump";
    //caption = '<div class="nivo-caption" ><p><b>From:</b> '+from+'</p><p><b>Age:</b> '+age+'</p><p><b>Years running the Peachtree:</b> '+yearsRun+'</p><p><b>What would you tweet right now?</b></p><p>'+tweet+'</p></div>';

    imgSrc = $(this).attr("url");
    lilImg = '<a id="' + jumpID + '"><img src="' + imgSrc + '" width="130px" height="130px"/><div><h3>' + name + '</h3></div></a>';

    bigImg = '<img src="' + imgSrc + '" width="260px" height="260px"/>';


    $('<li><div id="' + gridID + '">' + lilImg + '</div></li>').appendTo('.cbp-rfgrid');

    $('<a href="' + jumpID + '"><div id="' + slideID + '"><img src="' + imgSrc + '" data-thumb="' + imgSrc + '" alt=""  style="display:inline;"/></div></a>').appendTo('#slider');

    //$('<div id="'+ slideID +'"><p><b>From:</b> '+from+'</p><p><b>Age:</b> '+age+'</p><p><b>Years running the Peachtree:</b> '+yearsRun+'</p><p><b>What would you tweet right now?</b></p><p>'+tweet+'</p></div>').appendTo('#inside');
    //$('<div id="' + slideID + '"><p><b>From:</b> '+from+'</p><p><b>Age:</b> '+age+'</p><p><b>Years running the Peachtree:</b> '+yearsRun+'</p><p><b>What would you tweet right now?</b></p><p>'+tweet+'</p></div>').appendTo('.nivo-html-caption');
    $('#' +slideID).append('<p><b>From:</b> '+from+'</p><p><b>Age:</b> '+age+'</p><p><b>Years running the Peachtree:</b> '+yearsRun+'</p><p><b>What would you tweet right now?</b></p><p>'+tweet+'</p>');

    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider();
        //$('#slider').data('nivoslider').slideTo(1);
        $('#slider').hide();
    });

    //make image grid click to open lightbox
    $('#'+gridID).click(function(event){
        $('#hiddenLayer').show();
        $('#slider').show();
        //$('#slider').data('nivoslider').slideTo(1);


    }); 

    //close lightbox
    $('#hiddenLayer').click(function(event){
        $('#slider').hide();
        $('#hiddenLayer').hide();
    });
```

And the html:

```
<ul class="cbp-rfgrid"> 
        <!--This is where the images get rendered -->
        </ul>


        <!--slider info-->
        <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
            <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">

            </div>

            <div class="nivo-html-caption">
                <!--<div id="block"></div>-->
                </div>

        <!--end slider info-->

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer can be found here:

http://www.soslignes-ecrivain-public.fr/Nivo-Slider-Linking-to-a-specific-Slide.html

Required adding another xml variable, but it works.